# Why in the new Vulkan dynamic rendering we specify the stencil and depth attachments separately?

Tags: vulkan

When you create a render pass subpass description you give a pointer to the colour attachments:

```
VkSubpassDescription::pColorAttachments
```

and a pointer to the depth and stencil attachment:

```
VkSubpassDescription::pDepthStencilAttachment;
```

However in the new dynamic rendering method of the API we can specify them separately:

```
VkRenderingInfo::pColorAttachments;
VkRenderingInfo::pDepthAttachment;
VkRenderingInfo::pStencilAttachment;
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's reserved for future use cases where the formats for depth and/or stencil may differ. Afaik there is no use-case for something like that yet.

Comment: I was wondering about this as well, forgot to set stencil aspect mask for my format `VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT`, and got a validation error hinting at this extension: [VK_KHR_separate_depth_stencil_layouts](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_separate_depth_stencil_layouts.html). I suppose that is related.?